# Returning the record 'on the same row' for the last in a given column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I tried out with `MAX()`, `LAST()`, etc ... but failed.
Say I have the following `MySQL` table called `mytable`:

```
date    temp   prcp   visib
1/1/15   30     0.1    100
1/2/15   20     0.2    100
1/3/15   30     0.0    100
1/4/15   10     0.1    100
1/5/15   20     NULL   100
1/6/15   10     NULL   100
```

How do I return the date for the last prcp record that is 1/4/15 (to keep the things simple, say NULL values are always grouped at the end) ??

Comment: `WHERE prcp IS NOT NULL ORDER by DATE asc/desc LIMIT 1`

Comment: `MAX(date)` should have worked. Please show what you tried.

Comment: i don't remember exactly the many things I tried. Following Barmar's suggestion above, I go for : SELECT `prcp` FROM `mytable` WHERE `prcp` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM myTable
WHERE prcp is not null
ORDER BY date DESC
```

and if the date is a string, you can convert it to a date by ...

```
ORDER BY CAST(date AS DATE) DESC
```